# JQuery Ajax call not passing parameters to `Controller Method` in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

In Ajax call I'm passing a model parameter to the Controller Method but no data is passing to the Controller.

```
 var Model =
  {
     email: "123",
     phone:"2323"
  };
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: `/Home/AddEmailPhone/`,
    data: Model,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length);
    },

    failure: function (data) {
       console.log("failure");
    }, 
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("error");
    }

});
```

And Controller Method look like

```
 public JsonResult AddEmailPhone([FromBody]EmailPhoneModel Model)
 {
      Return Json("json");
 }
```

The ajax call successfully calling the `Method` but no data is passing.

I also tried to pass value through url
like:

```
 `/Home/AddEmailPhone/email= ${email}&phone=${phone}`
```

this worked in my another project where I was passing an `int` value but this time no one is working.
what's the wrong I'm doing?

Comment: Try doing `AddEmailPhone([FromBody]EmailPhoneModel Model)`

Comment: @ Hubert Jarema I forgot write I have also tried with `[FromBody]`

Comment: Does your `EmailPhoneNumber` has public getters and setters for `Email` and `Phone`?

Comment: Sure they are all public property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your model has public properties and url is mapped correctly the only missing bit I see is calling stringify for normalizing your json.

```
data: JSON.stringify(Model),
```

I have tested this with:

```
public JsonResult AddEmailPhone(EmailPhoneModel Model)
{
    return Json("json");
}
```

But I don't have Core installed.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use  $.get**

```
//at client side
var url = "apiurl/method1";
var par1="valu";
$.get(url, { contParam1: par1}, function (data)
   {
     //write code here after success 
   } 
    );
//at server side
[HttpGet("method1")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> method1([FromQuery(Name = "contParam1")] string contParam1)
            {

            }
```